# MarkLogic rest service returns 405 Method Not Allowed from selected servers

Tags: linux, rest, curl, marklogic, marklogic-8

MarkLogic 8, Linux (Centos & RH6). I've set-up the same REST service, User, and Roles on each of three MarkLogic instances (2x Centos,1x RH6). I've separately checked the settings for these entries are identical for each host. The Centos boxes are VMs (VirtualBox on my local machine) where one is the original and the other a clone of this original VM). The RH6 machine is a networked development server. I'm using 'curl', via windows 7 command line, to 'PUT' a single test file into the Documents database. The Curl command I use is :

```
curl  --basic --user <user>:<pwd> --upload-file "<file path>"   -H "Content-type: text/plain" -X PUT "http://<host name>:<port number>/v1/documents?database=<database name>&uri=<test uri>"
```

I get a "405 Method not allowed", as a simple XML document [source = MarkLogic?] from ML on the RH6 and the cloned Centos machine but not from my original Centos VM where ML shows the file has loaded correctly. MarkLogic error logs show no errors on any of the hosts.

Any ideas on where should I start looking to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed the fact I hadn't entered the default error handler and url rewriter settings of "/MarkLogic/rest-api/error-handler.xqy" and "/MarkLogic/rest-api/rewriter.xml" on the appserver on the two ML hosts that were reporting the issue.